# Magento 2 : How to move register-link next to minicart?

Tags: magento2.2.3, header, toplinks, create-account

I want to move the `Create An Account` button, near the mini cart in the header section.

Answer (score 0):

You can move 'Create an Account' link near mini cart. Use move element in below file. Once moved need to do css changes as per need.

> app/design/frontend/[vendor-name]/[theme-name]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<move element="register-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="minicart"/>
```